# nodejs logger module wrong context

Tags: node.js

I have a simple nodejs logger module to print 'time, context and message'

```
module.exports = {
  init: (c) => {
    const config = c || {};
    const context = config.context || 'ROOT';
    console.log('test', c, config);
    return {
      d: (message) => {
        console.log(`${new Date()} [${context}] Debug - ${message}`);
      },
      i: (message) => {
        console.log(`${new Date()} [${context}] Info  - ${message}`);
      },
      w: (message) => {
        console.log(`${new Date()} [${context}] Warn  - ${message}`);
      },
      e: (message) => {
        console.error(`${new Date()} [${context}] Error - ${message}`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I require this module from other modules inside my app.

`const logger = require('./logger').init('Database');`
or
`const logger = require('./logger').init('WebSocket');`

But for some reason from every logging on my console, the context is 'ROOT' but `console.log('test', c, config);` is called multiple times with the right c and config.

I know that modules are like singletons in one app scope but it is called...
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you call `require('./logger').init('Database')`, your config equals 'Database' so `config.context` is *undefined* and `context` defaults to 'ROOT'.

Answer (score 1):

The way you invoke your init method is malformed.

You should write for example:

```
const logger = require('./logger').init({context:'Database'});
```